# pre-compiled view not affecting performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

**EDIT :**

This question is not about compiled queries, it is about generating the EF database view at compile time.

From the ADO.NET team blog: [Exploring the Performance of the ADO.NET Entity Framework - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/04/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-1.aspx):

> View Generation 56%– A big part of creating an abstracted view of the database is providing the actual view for queries and updates in the store’s native language. During this step, the store views are created. The good news is there is a way of making view generation part of the build process so that this step can be avoided at run time.

---

The first database call in my web app takes about 2.5 seconds instead of ~30 ms for subsequent identical calls.

I generated a precompiled view source file using the T4 template from the [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx), but it has made no detectable difference.

The T4 template takes about 2.5 seconds to run and the generated code compiles.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think precompiled views would have even the slightest bearing on how long it takes to make your "first database call"?

Comment: @KirkWoll I read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/04/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-1.aspx) - am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "first".  The first in page life cycle, the first after a code change, the first after a server re-boot.  First what?

Comment: So you think the compilation of the view costs no ressources? Ouch. Naturally the first time is slow.

Comment: @TomTom Why does generating the view and compiling it into my assembly not make any difference to the time taken on the first call?

Comment: @user, I am confused because there is no relationship between compiling a view and making a database call.  Compiling a view utlizes a completely different set of resources than running SQL.

Comment: @KirkWoll I have put more info in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

The Generated View derived from EntityViewContainer must be in the assembly that contains the STOs Self-Tracking Objects, not the one that contains the edmx model.

Comment: You should except your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your first call to your application after a build, the web server will have unloaded the application, and the first call "starts" the application again, and everything that is associated with that.  This has nothing to do with pre-compiled views.  Therefore, the first call will always take longer as the application is loaded.

Incidentally, the same thing will happen on your production server.  An idle worker-pool might well unload your application, and the *next* call will load the application again, taking significantly longer to perform than usual requests.

Comment: Yes - I can see that happening, but I am timing just the database calls - those are the times I put in my question.

Comment: @user1055425, your first database call will take longer too.  Remember, behind the scenes, the framework might well be pooling database connections.  Subsequent connections take relatively little time compared to the initial one.

Comment: I have put more info in my question. Surely it shouldn't take 2.5 seconds to open a db connection?

Comment: Too many variables to say. How busy the server is, the path to it from where the app is running. Can't see you making much difference in code, except a dummy call to the db on startup to force that first call "invisibly".