# Pre compiled views are not working

Tags: performance, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-mapping

I was trying to use pre-compiled views for good performance, i generated the views successfully and everything is same in compile time and at run time .edmx. Earlier there was mismtach of data provider for default connection factory, .edmx always take SqlClient provider for default connection factory even you change the default connection factory to some other data provider but this situation was overcome when  i commented out the constructor of the class which was inheriting DbContext, after this connection provder in .edmx file was same what i specified in the default connection factory in app.config.
So, everthing is same in compile time generated .Edmx and runtime .edmx.

But when i am generating views at compile time and using the views to optimize the performance 
, then following exception is thrown, when i call dbcontext.SaveChanges()

"The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'DatabaseContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views."

above exception suggests that there is some mistmatch but i checked the edmx and everything is same. so What is the issue. Or i have been through this

[pre-compiled view not affecting performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272461/pre-compiled-view-not-affecting-performance)

as it suggesting different assembly issues . So, for my case i am having a project1 which is having few POCO class and different project2 that refers the project1 and use the POCO classes of project1 and DbContext class has been define in project2 and i am generating views for project2, so what exactly is the issue
Thanks in Advance for helping